# Application Express on Ubuntu Server refused to connect port 8080

Tags: server, firewall, oracle

Hi I am new to Ubuntu server and trying to get Oracle 11 xe with application express running on a headless VM Ubuntu server. Installation seems to be all good and everything running well from sqlplus. Because the VM is headless I cant test apex with a browser set to localhost so I turned on remote connections for the listener using the oracle instructions.

```
EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETLISTENERLOCALACCESS(FALSE);
```

However when I put the address into the browser (chrome) of another machine I get the following error:

**This site can’t be reached
10.10.74.228 refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

I think it is the server not allowing anything through port 8080 but dont know enough about ubuntu to know what to change.

Using netstat i can see:

```
tcp6        0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      962/tnslsnr
```

Can anyone tell me what I can do to check if port 8080 is being blocked and or what I can do to resolve the problem.

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:**
Before you ask I can access that IP address (different port) as I am using the same machine to connect to it via putty :)

Comment: Is there some way to ping port 8080 from command line to see if it is working internally. would be easier if I could just open a browser :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprised no one even suggested things to check but in the end I have solved it anyway.

As I said in my problem description the server was a VM so when I was trying to access the 8080 port it was actually on the host not my VM. 8080 on the host was actually mapped to another VM and was not setup to receive anything.
This issue was resolved by mapping port 8081 on the host to my 8080.

I hope this helps someone else in the future.